# Can I reverse the modulo operator in complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

Can I reverse the modulo operator in complex numbers?

Say I have

$$|z_1||z_2|$$

where $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$.

Then is it legit to say that:

$$=z_1z_2$$

Comment: What's left side of the equality in the last line?

Comment: $|z_1||z_2|$ is always a real number. On the other hand $z_1z_2$ might not be real...

Comment: No, just as with real numbers. $|-1||1| = |1||1|$.

Comment: Don't say *modulo* but *modulus*.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that $$|z_1||z_2|=|z_1z_2|.$$